# ¿Como puedo simplificar esta funcion con variables Date() en App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

estoy haciendo unas tablas en Google Sheets, y aplicando unas funciones personalizadas, hice una función y sirve, pero la duda es a ver si se podría simplificar, lo que hace la función es tomar un "Input" de fecha y me lo transforma en el numero del día del año, pero como si todos los años fueran bisiestos, ósea, 1ro de enero seria "001" y 31 de diciembre "366" como resultado, no importa que año tome en el input, siempre será bisiesto, pero el código es demasiado largo porque solo utilizo condicionales para el return, parte del código es el siguiente...

```
function DAYNUMBER(input) {

  var a = new Date(input);
  var b = a.getDate();
  var c = a.getMonth();
  var d = b + "/" + c;

  if (d == '1/0'){
        return '001';
    }
    else if (d == '2/0'){
        return '002';
    }
    else if (d == '3/0'){
        return '003';
    }
    else if (d == '4/0'){
        return '004';
    }
    else if (d == '5/0'){
        return '005';
    }
    else if (d == '6/0'){
        return '006';
    }
```

Y obvio termina...

```
    else if (d == '27/11'){
        return '362';
    }
    else if (d == '28/11'){
        return '363';
    }
    else if (d == '29/11'){
        return '364';
    }
    else if (d == '30/11'){
        return '365';
    }
    else {
        return '366';
    }
   }
```

Si se puede arreglar me seria de gran ayuda, gracias!!

Comment: Parece haber sido respondida en: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619879
Puede ser que te interese exactamente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28919172/16512497

Answer (score 0):

Creo que esta seria una posible solución para tu pregunta

```
function DAYNUMBER(input) {    
  let now = new Date(input);
  let start = new Date(now.getFullYear(), 0, 0);
  let diff = now - start;
  let oneDay = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;
  let day = Math.floor(diff / oneDay);

  //NUMERO DEL DIA DEL AÑO
  console.log('Dia del año: ' + day);

  //LE DOY EL FORMATO REQUIERO 00# ó 0## ó ###
  let stringDay = String(day)
  let result;
  if(stringDay.length < 10) result = '00'+stringDay
  else if (stringDay.length < 100) result = '0'+ stringDay
  else result = stringDay

  return result;    
}
```

Espero te sirva